# State of selected items in view or viewmodel?

Tags: mvvm

Myself and my colleague were having a discussion about MVVM and how lists and selected items should be stored in view / viewmodel.

I think the viewmodel should only offer up the data and allow the view to interpret it how it likes. It could display it as a list with a selected item or it could show it completely differently.

Therefore I think the viewmodel should look like this:

```
public class MajorVM
{
    ObservableCollection<MinorVM> List
}
```

And the view like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Listbox Key=ListBox Items=Binding DataContext.List />
    <ContentControl Content=Binding ListBox.SelectedItem />
</Grid>
```

My colleague thinks that I'm changing between data contexts making the view code harder to follow.

My colleague believes the viewmodel should contain the state of the view and that this will allow easier manipulation of the view in future. E.g. controlling selection via the viewmodel.

Therefore it would look like:

```
public class MajorVM
{
    ObservableCollection<MinorVM> List
    MinorVM SelectedItem
}
```

With a view that looks like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Listbox Items=Binding DataContext.List />
    <ContentControl Content=Binding DataContext.SelectedItem />
</Grid>
```

To me this doesn't seem correct because the viewmodel now has a SelectedItem property on it that isn't mentioned anywhere other than the view. It's a view implementation on the viewmodel.

Comment: In *your* viewModel example (the one containing just an observable collection), how does the ViewModel know which item has been selected?

Comment: It doesn't. The viewmodel doesn't do anything with the selected item. It's only for determining which content is shown in the ContentControl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its generally better to bind controls in the View to Properties of the ViewModel rather than other aspects of the View.

There is one clear benefit to the ViewModel having SelectedItem in this case, which is that without it no item is initially selected when the view is displayed.

It's hard to put a line in the sand that demarks 'this functionality is ok to add to a control' and 'this functionality should be put in the viewmodel' though.

Effectively here you are simply making a compound control with a selection and detail view. There's nothing which makes that quantitatively different from, say a ComboBox/DropDown control.

But if we do want to add some custom logic, say we want to select extra info from the database for the selected item. Having the selected item and an ItemSelected command on the ViewModel will make this much easier.

With WPF you have a number of options when it comes to adding custom logic.

- Code Behind page. You can handle events and directly manipulate controls
- Custom Controls. You can override the behaviours of a control, changing its logic.
- Behaviours. You can add extra behaviour which can be linked to a control in the view
- Binding - to VM. You can bind controls to properties of its data context
- Binding - to View. You can bind to properties of other Controls
- Styles - You can use styles and data triggers to change the properties of Controls
- Data Templates. You can customise a control with a Data Template
- Content Templates. You can change the way a control presents itself
- Custom Converters. You can put logic in converters to change the way a binding works eg EnumToBrush

You are overloaded with options and they all work in different ways. But if you are doing MVVM try to favour Binding to VM and Behaviours

Comment: Do you have any links regarding your very first comment? I've tried looking on google and I'm not really finding anything on the subject.

Comment: no. but as an authority on the subject you can trust that i am correct

Comment: I don't doubt your credentials and I understand that to you this might be a simple question with a simple answer but I think it would be poor form for me to accept this answer on that basis alone. Your only argument is essentially the first line without anything backing it up.

Comment: what about paragraph 4?

Comment: Also, what im saying in the rest of the answer is that there is no clear point at which you say 'this must be in the VM!'

Comment: but since you are doing MVVM. your question is somewhat self answering. The whole point of MVVM is to bind the View to the ViewModel and by binding to the view you are avoiding doing that

Comment: you are probably better waiting a few days before accepting an answer though. Someone might be typing the opposite to my answer.. right..... now....

Comment: I've always been under the opinion (perhaps illusion) that the viewmodel and view should be fiercely independent. To me changing your viewmodel to suit the view is akin to adding properties to it so it can be unit tested more easily.

Comment: That is the classic view, but these days I think the more practical approach of one VM per View is in the majority. The ViewModel really is only there to make the view's life easier. Adding properties and methods to it as required is fine. If you have two Views which are diverging, just make a copy of the VM

Comment: Even if you have one VM per View, adding a property which the VM ends up not caring about whatsoever seems silly.  If the VM needed to *do* something with the selected item, then it should be on the VM, but in the OPs case, the VM just gets the list and gives it to the view and doesn't care.

Comment: @andy but you do do something. something you could have achieved in a different way to be sure. but is that way MVVM?

Comment: It is.   The view model is still responsible for getting the list in the first place. Adding a pointless property to the vm which it never gives a damn about doesn't make it more mvvm.

Comment: @andy I think I have covered that objection. there are 20 ways to bind your Model, because you use one doesn't make the others pointless. They are 'alternatives'

Comment: I have accepted this answer because all the answers share the same sentiment but this one contains the most detail and alternative options.

Comment: It has nothing to do with what I use or don't; one alternative has you write code which preserves a purist approach, but has no value, the other does not.  Changing the design of a VM for purist reasons, when the VM need not care about this property, has no value.

Answer (score 4):

Typically, a SelectedItem target binding belongs on the ViewModel.

This is because you usually want to *do* something with the SelectedItem (edit, delete, etc).

Having the SelectedItem on the VM also allows you to change the SelectedItem from VM code in reaction to other events in the system.

Now, if this specific SelectedItem is only for viewing purposes then you could make the case that it only belongs in the view.  However, I find this to be an unusual approach for the MVVM pattern and I can see where it could be considered confusing.

Answer (score 3):

> The viewmodel doesn't do anything with the selected item. It's only for determining which content is shown in the ContentControl.

Then you don't need a `SelectedItem` property in the ViewModel. Simple as that.

However, that means that you must now take responsibility for updating the `ContentControl` in the View yourself using code behind, whereas if you'd exposed a `SelectedItem` on the ViewModel instead, you could have simply used Linq and data binding to accomplish the same thing in the ViewModel.

Technically, what data you decide to display in your ContentControl is a business rule, not a UI function.  If you can implement such business rules in the ViewModel, it is better from a maintenance perspective, since the View doesn't have to care about the data mechanics.

Comment: "However, that means that you must now take responsibility for updating the ContentControl in the View yourself using code behind"  Assuming that the ContentControl simply isn't just showing the data; its possible there is nothing to be done in the ContentControl that can't be accomplished with bindings.

Comment: yeah in the example the contentcontrol is bound directly.